# Could not find module '...' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, dll, operating-system, spyder, ctypes

I'm trying to run a code and I'm stuck at the first lines of code.
The code is the following:

```
import os
import time
from MIRcatSDKConstants import *
from MIRcatSDKHelpers import ArmAndWaitForTemp

os.chdir("C:/...") # Change the working directory to reference libraries based on version of python x32 or x64
SDK = CDLL("MIRcatSDK")
```

once I've imported some packages (ctypes is imported from another module), I run CDLL (or ctypes.CDLL) to open a .dll file in the folder specified in os.chdir, but I keep having the same error "Could not find module 'MIRcatSDK' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.".

Curiously, if I run the same code on another computer, it runs smoothly, so I wonder if I need to install any package or so.
I'm using Spyder with Python 3.9.7, thanks!

Comment: Recent versions of Python don't search the current directory by default and need `CDLL('./MIRcatSDK')` for example.  Is the other computer using a different version of Python?  Also, your DLL could be referencing another dependent DLL that isn't installed on the failing computer.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I will try that. Something I noticed is that my script (running on windows 10 on a Mac through bootcamp) does not accept \, while others computer where I’ve tested it, and it works (windows PCs), accept both \ and /, and I’m wondering if maybe this confuses the script. Maybe it’s a Mac issue?

Comment: Only Windows supports backslashes, but will work with forward slashes in Python code too.

Comment: I see. I was thinking that probably the easiest thing would be to open that .dll with another PC, save it on a file, and load that file in my computer. Is that possible?